# Parsing error when converting milliseconds to a DateTime format in Joda

Tags: java, jodatime, illegalargumentexception

I have the foloowing snippet which convert milli-seconds to a Date according to a format. I am using Joda-time 2.3.

```
final Long currentMs = new DateTime().getMillis());
DateTimeFormatter currentMsTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTime dt = currentMsTimeFormat.parseDateTime(String.valueOf(currentMs));
System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

When I run this program I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1455711149006" is malformed at "9006"
```

where `1455711149006` is the value of `currentMs`.

Comment: Please read the doc. How `"1455711149006"` is supposed to be parsed with `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`. Also note that the posted code create a DateTime instance, transforms it to ms then try to parse it back to a DateTime, what is the point

Comment: Milli-seconds can't directly parsed with your format. You should convert it to some `Date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [constructor for `DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long)) that takes milliseconds since EPOCH. So you probably want:

```
new DateTime(currentMs);
```